# KNN regression: Why does my In sample RMSE look like my out of sample RMSE across K values?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm expecting the RMSE plot for my KNN regression model to look like the above image but I'm getting the below when running my code [hosted here](https://github.com/PortWhisperer/MachineLearningStudies/blob/master/ML_hw_1.py). Any ideas on what could cause this? I believe something is wrong.

[image: expected plot shape]
 [[image: my plot shape]

Answer (score 0):

I was calculating mean squared error (lines 50 and 51) by comparing the fitted model with Y, instead of Y hat. When I changed to Y hat, the issue resolved.
[image]